# How to properly use app and user tokens with the Facebook Score API on iOS

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to post a high score to the Facebook Graph API in iOS, but having no luck getting past all the token stuff.  I've modified the iOS library to store the app token and the user token and I swap the app token in when making the post to `https://graph.facebook.com/{my user id}/scores`, but I keep getting an error back about needing a user token.  When I swap the user token in, it tells me I need an app token.

I figured it might be something like the user token getting switched back in before the request completed but I have double and triple checked that the request comes back with the app token I received as the `access_token` post value.  According to the debugging I've been doing, I need both a user access token and an app access token.

*After called oauth/access_token*

```
NSString *tempToken = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request responseText] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
//Response is something like "access_token={APP ID}|{SOME HASHED VALUE}"
[fb setAppAccessToken:[tempToken substringFromIndex:13]];
[fb setAccessToken:[fb appAccessToken]];
NSMutableDictionary *scoreParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"20", @"score", nil];
[fb requestWithGraphPath:@"{MY USER ID}/scores" andParams:scoreParams andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
[fb setAccessToken:[fb userAccessToken]];
```

With USER ACCESS TOKEN "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token."

With APP ACCESS TOKEN "A user access token is required to request this resource."

I'm also using publish_actions as a permission.